# Can I use the same std::promise and std::future objects multiple times?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, promise

Can I use the same `std::promise` and `std::future` objects multiple times?

For example, I want to send several values many times from Thread-1 to Thread-2. Can I use promise/future multiple times, and how to do it thread-safety?

```
            std::promise<int> send_value;
            std::future<int> receive_value = send_value.get_future();

            std::thread t1 = std::thread([&]()
            {
                while (!exit_flag) {
                    int value = my_custom_function_1();
                    send_value.set_value(value);
                }
            });

            std::thread t2 = std::thread([&]()
            {
                while (!exit_flag) {
                    int value = receive_value.get();
                    my_custom_function_2(value);
                }
            });
```

Comment: No, you can't. Calling `set_value/set_exception` more then once raises an exception.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16075550/1387438)